# Mostrar mensagem de sucesso ao arrastar componente com jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5, #sortable6").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Este jQuery arrasta uma div para dentro da outra, até aí, ok!
Quero que, ao arrastar e obtiver sucesso, dê um `alert('arrastado com sucesso')`.

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [api do plugin](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) é sempre uma boa referência, no seu caso especificamente na parte de eventos.

Para isso, depende um pouquinho do contexto, tem 3 eventos, `stop()`, `update()` e `receive()`.

O `stop()` e disparado sempre que você, obviamente, para de arrastar o elemento.

Já o `update()` é bem semelhante, mas dispara somente se o houver uma mudança de posição.

O `receive()` que acho ser o ideal para você, é disparado quando você solta um elemento em outra lista conectada com a de origem.

O código é bem simples:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3, #sortable4, #sortable5, #sortable6").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        update: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Arrastado com sucesso com alteração.')
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            alert('Arrastado com sucesso, mesma posição.')
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            alert('Arrastado com sucesso para outra lista.')
        },
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Agora é só decidir qual que é o melhor para você.

Comment: Entendi, a ideia, é eu chamar um carregando, e atualizar no banco de dados e dar um append da nova lista...